# Monitoring the asyncio event loop

Tags: python-3.x, profiler, python-asyncio

I am writing an application using python3 and am trying out asyncio for the first time. One issue I have encountered is that some of my coroutines block the event loop for longer than I like. I am trying to find something along the lines of top for the event loop that will show how much wall/cpu time is being spent running each of my coroutines. If there isn't anything already existing does anyone know of a way to add hooks to the event loop so that I can take measurements?

I have tried using cProfile which gives some helpful output, but I am more interested in time spent blocking the event loop, rather than total execution time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Event loop can already track if coroutines take much CPU time to execute. To see it you should [enable debug mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.set_debug) with `set_debug` method:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def main():
    time.sleep(1)  # Block event loop


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_debug(True)  # Enable debug
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

In output you'll see:

```
Executing <Task finished coro=<main() [...]> took 1.016 seconds
```

By default it shows warnings for coroutines that blocks for more than 0.1 sec. It's not documented, but based on asyncio [source code](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/a791d884b9110b59bada18c2dddd399e6adc40fd/asyncio/base_events.py#L252), looks like you can change `slow_callback_duration` attribute to modify this value.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`call_later`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.call_later). Periodically run callback that will log/notify the difference of loop's time and period interval time.

```
class EventLoopDelayMonitor:

    def __init__(self, loop=None, start=True, interval=1, logger=None):
        self._interval = interval
        self._log = logger or logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self._loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        if start:
            self.start()

    def run(self):
        self._loop.call_later(self._interval, self._handler, self._loop.time())

    def _handler(self, start_time):
        latency = (self._loop.time() - start_time) - self._interval
        self._log.error('EventLoop delay %.4f', latency)
        if not self.is_stopped():
            self.run()

    def is_stopped(self):
        return self._stopped

    def start(self):
        self._stopped = False
        self.run()

    def stop(self):
        self._stopped = True
```

example

```
import time

async def main():
    EventLoopDelayMonitor(interval=1)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(2)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

output

```
EventLoop delay 0.0013
EventLoop delay 1.0026
EventLoop delay 0.0014
EventLoop delay 0.0015
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! Can a blocking loop has side effect on others loops ?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this in 2019, this might be a better answer: [yappi](https://github.com/sumerc/yappi). With Yappi version 1.2.1>=, you can natively profile coroutines and see exactly how much wall or cpu time is spent inside a coroutine.

See [here](https://github.com/sumerc/yappi/blob/master/doc/coroutine-profiling.md) for details on this coroutine profiling.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on one of the answers, if you want to monitor your loop *and* detect hangs, here's a snippet to do just that. It launches a separate thread that checks whether the loop's tasks yielded execution recently enough.

```
def monitor_loop(loop, delay_handler):
loop = loop
last_call = loop.time()

INTERVAL = .5  # How often to poll the loop and check the current delay.
def run_last_call_updater():
    loop.call_later(INTERVAL, last_call_updater)
def last_call_updater():
    nonlocal last_call
    last_call = loop.time()
    run_last_call_updater()
run_last_call_updater()

def last_call_checker():
    threading.Timer(INTERVAL / 2, last_call_checker).start()
    if loop.time() - last_call > INTERVAL:
        delay_handler(loop.time() - last_call)
threading.Thread(target=last_call_checker).start()
```